# gcloud cron jobs and laravel

Tags: laravel, cron, gcloud

I am trying to execute an api in laravel every minute.

The api's method is `GET`. However I could not specify the method in the `cron.yaml` file. Could I use `DELETE` method here and how? The code should be deployed on google cloud.

I have created a `cron.yaml` file that has the following format:

```
cron:
  - description: "every minutes job"
    url: /deletestories
    schedule: every 1 mins
    retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
    max_doublings: 5
```

I also created the api `deletestories` that delete rows under specific conditions.

However this isn't working, and when I open google cloud console I could not found any error or any cron job executed.

Comment: Is this a Google App Engine application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `cron.yaml` file appears to be a Google App Engine cron configuration. If this is correct then only the `GET` method is supported, you cannot use `DELETE`.

The GAE cron service itself consists simply of scheduled `GET` requests that your app needs to handle. From [Scheduling Tasks With Cron for Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron) (the same applies to other languages and to the [flexible environment cron](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) as well):

> A cron job makes an HTTP `GET` request to a URL as scheduled. The
>   handler for that URL executes the logic when it is called.

You also need to deploy your `cron.yaml` file for it to be effective. You should be able to see the deployed cron configuration in the developer console's [`Cron Jobs`](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/taskqueues/cron) tab under the `Task Queues` Menu (where you can also manually trigger any of the cron jobs). The performed `GET` requests for the respective cron jobs should appear in your app's request logs as well, when executed.

Comment: thank you,  i was  deploying my  application so  the cron.yaml file is not effective, however when i deploy the specific file cron.yaml , it worked